# Factorization $a^x-1 | (a^x)^k - 1$

Tags: divisibility, factoring

$a^x-1 | (a^x)^k - 1$

Is this expression true, and if yes how can I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: recognize the pattern $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$, which is the sum of the first ${n-1}$ terms of a geometric sequence.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now. But, can you give me another hint ;) to prove it by using factoring?